# Почему не страбатывает array_filter?

Tags: php

вот код вместо тысячи код

```
var_dump($model-image);
```

получаю

```
object(common\models\Image)#2028 (9) { 
["class"]=> NULL 
["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(13) {
  ["title_alt"]=> string(46) "Ложное обвинение (сериал)" 
  ["path"]=> string(15) "serial/2016/10/" 
  ["name"]=> string(10) "979247.jpg" 
  ["for_home"]=> int(1) }  
}
```

потом делаю так

```
$img = array_filter($model->image, function($item) {
                return $item->for_home == 1;
            });
var_dump($img)
```

получаю `null` почему я не получаю объект? в `$img`

Comment: Странно, что этот код у вас не выдает ошибку. $model->image перебирается как массив атрибутов. Соответственно, $item в функции - это либо int, либо string, но никак не объект, у которого можно было бы обратиться к свойству  ->for_home

Comment: @cronfy это не полный объект его часть для читабельности вам весь опубликовать ?

Comment: полностью не обязательно, но хоть как-то покажите, что у вас в model->image ? - объект, массив объектов или еще что-то.

Comment: в принципе вопрос решил там Yii2 заморочка была спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну наверное функция для массивов, не применяется к объекту.

Если хотите атрибуты отфильтровать, то стоит их все же передавать в функцию:

`array_filter($model->image->attributes, ...`

[attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getAttributes-detail)  - вернет массив атрибутов и их значений

Но не ясно чего ожидаете в результате, можно и просто получить значение свойства `for_home`:

`$model->image->for_home`

или

`$model->image->getAttributes('for_home')`

Comment: эта функция работает с объектами уже проверено. Мне надо не отфильтровать а надо выбрать из 5 или 6 объектов того вида, что я показал объект со свойством for_home =1

Comment: вы наверное имеете ввиду что она работает с массивом объектов, в вашем вопросе вы показываете что пытаетесь применить ее к объекту